# Install New Object in Real Database Cause Error in OpenERP v7?

Tags: xml, runtime-error, odoo

I have develop two new object name mrp_extend and also mrp_production_output in my development PC which is work great. Then now I would like to update into my real time server into the addons server. After that I click on Update Module List then I go to find my this two new object and install the mrp_extend which work great. But when I click install the mrp_production_output then it give me error:

```
ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!
```

I not idea why in my development server work great but when install into my server then will have this issue?

Below is my XML file for my mrp_production_output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

        <!-- Add new form in new form for Production Output (By Henry on 24/Oct/2013) -->
        <record id="mrp_production_output_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mrp.production.output.form</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.production.output</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Production Output" version="7.0">
                    <group string="Production Output" colspan="4" col="4">
                        <field name="batch_number" string="Batch Number"/>
                        <field name="finish_date" string="Finish Date"/>
                        <field name="product_id" string="Product" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, context)"/>
                        <field name="finish_product_quantity" string="Finish Produce Quantity" on_change="on_change_calculate_production_cost(total_raw_mat_cost,total_packaging_cost,finish_product_quantity)"/>
                        <field name="product_uom" string="Product Unit Of Measure"/>
                        <field name="total_packaging_cost" string="Packaging Cost/Extra Cost" on_change="on_change_calculate_production_cost(total_raw_mat_cost,total_packaging_cost,finish_product_quantity)"/>
                        <field name="system_message" string="System Message"/>
                        <field name="remarks" string="Remarks"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <group string="BOM Lists">
                            <field name="bom_lines" nolabel="1" options="{'reload_on_button': true}">
                                <tree string="BOM Lists">
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                    <field name="product_id"/>
                                    <field name="product_qty" sum="Expected Total Produce Qty"/>
                                    <field name="product_uom" string="Unit of Measure" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                                    <field name="total_final_cost" string="Total Costs" sum="Total Costs"/>
                                    <field name="location_dest_id"/>
                                    <field name="date_planned"/>
                                    <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                        <group>
                            <group colspan="4" col="4">
                            <field name="expected_produce_quantity" string="Expected Produce Quantity"/>
                            <field name="total_production_cost" string="Total Production Cost" />
                            <field name="total_raw_mat_cost" string="Raw Material Cost" />                          
                            <field name="total_unit_cost" string="Total Unit Cost" bold="True"/>
                        </group>                   
                    </group>             
                </form>
               <!--<xpath expr="/form/sheet" position="after">
                    <div class="oe_chatter">
                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                    </div>
                </xpath>-->
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- Add new tree in new form for Production Output (By Henry on 24/Oct/2013) -->
        <record id="mrp_production_output_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mrp.production.output.tree</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.production.output</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Production Output">
                    <field name="batch_number" string="Batch Number"/>
                    <field name="finish_date" string="Finish Date"/>
                    <field name="product_id" string="Product"/>
                    <field name="expected_produce_quantity" string="Expected Produce Quantity"/>
                    <field name="finish_product_quantity" string="Finish Produce Quantity"/>
                    <field name="product_uom" string="Product Unit Of Measure"/>
                    <field name="total_raw_mat_cost" string="Raw Material Cost"/>
                    <field name="total_packaging_cost" string="Packaging Cost/Extra Cost"/>
                    <field name="total_production_cost" string="Total Production Cost"/>
                    <field name="total_unit_cost" string="Total Unit Cost"/>
                    <field name="system_message" string="System Message"/>
                    <field name="remarks" string="Remarks"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="mrp_production_output_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Production Output</field>
            <field name="res_model">mrp.production.output</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="mrp_production_output_child" 
        parent="mrp.menu_mrp_manufacturing" sequence="2"
        action="mrp_production_output_action" />

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the entire error log?

Comment: May I know where to find my error log in my server? Last time I follow this [link](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) to setup the openerp v7 in my server. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: if your server is a ubuntu server, type ps aux | grep ./openerp-server. it will check if any server with this name is running. Now type tail -f /var/log/openerp-server.log to see the log

Comment: I have type ps aux | grep ./openerp-server and what I get is `henry@openerpv7:~$ ps aux | grep ./openerp-server
openerp   1203  0.3 38.8 2587156 796212 ?      Sl   Oct29  51:18 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/openerp-server --config=/etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf --logfile=/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
henry    14192  0.0  0.0  13588   932 pts/0    R+   17:52   0:00 grep --color=auto ./openerp-server`

Comment: then I type `tail -f /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log` but I get an error: `henry@openerpv7:~$ tail -f /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
tail: cannot open `/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log' for reading: Permission denied` Please help!

Comment: try sudo /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log

Comment: after I type `try sudo /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log` then it show me this error: `sudo: must be setuid root`

Comment: Change user to login by sudo -i. then try tail -f /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log

Comment: Hi @PrajulPT, I already type in sudo -i but it still show me the error of 'sudo: must be setuid root'